# Converting base64 string to PNG

Tags: php

i am succesfully converting base64 string to png on xampp but when i run the same code on live site, everything works fine except the resultant image throws error "format unsupported or file corrupted"
Point is code working fine on xampp but not on live server.
below is my code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['image'])){
$url = $_POST['image'];
$user_name = $_POST['name'];
$file_name = $user_name.".png";
file_put_contents('temp/'.$file_name, file_get_contents($url));
}
```

Comment: If `image` is base64 encoded image data, you need to decode the image data before storing it as a PNG file.

Comment: You need to decode the base64 before writing into a file.